# Is there any function in openCV or another library that can tile squares within an arbitrary contour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have images where I've found some contours around dogs, e.g.:

[image: dog contour]

I want to tile squares/rectangles inside of the contour.  Is there an openCV (or other library) function for this?  I'm using Python.  I'd like it to look something like this:

[image: with squares now]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by first drawing rectangles over the entire image, then checking which ones were in the area with the dog:

```
# the image here is stored as the variable fg
# with b, g, r, and alpha channels
# the alpha channel is masking the dog part of the image
import cv2

b, g, r, a = cv2.split(fg)
fgcp = fg.copy()
h, w = fg.shape[:2]
h -= 1
w -= 1 # avoid indexing error
rectDims = [10, 10] # w, h of rectangles
hRects = h / rectDims[0]
wRects = w / rectDims[1]
for i in range(wRects):
    for j in range(hRects):
        pt1 = (i * rectDims[0], j * rectDims[1])
        pt2 = ((i + 1) * rectDims[0], (j + 1) * rectDims[1])
        # alpha is 255 over the part of the dog
        if a[pt1[1], pt1[0]] == 255 and a[pt2[1], pt2[0]] == 255:
            cv2.rectangle(fgcp, pt1, pt2, [0, 0, 255], 2)

cv2.imshow('', fgcp), cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

It's not necessarily the ideal implementation, but it works well enough.